# Mangled nested class namein the Java Language Specification

Tags: java, identifier, nested-class

Consider the following two classes:

```
// a.java
public class a
{
    public static class $b
    {

    }
}
```

```
// a$.java
public class a$
{
    public static class b
    {

    }
}
```

Obviously, due to inner/nested class name mangling, a$.b and a.$b will both be compiled to a class file named a$$b.class. When the command `javac a.java a$.java` is executed, the Oracle Java compiler (javac 1.7.0_45) produces the following output:

```
a$.java:3: error: duplicate class: a.$b
    public static class b
                  ^
1 error
```

Where does it say in the Java Language Specification that these class names (`a$.b` and `a.$b` ) clash, or is this just an established convention due to the output files having the same name?

Comment: I would presume it says this in whatever section of the JLS deals with name mangling of inner classes and thus defines that behavior. Not having a copy of the JLS, that's just a guess.

Comment: @keshlam Everyone has a copy of the JLS if they have the internet ;)

Comment: @BrianRoach Not everyone should be reading it, for legal reasons. I need to be a bit more careful than some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[6.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.1) which points to [3.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) which says:

> An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java digits, the first of which must be a Java letter.
>
> ...
>
> The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters A-Z (\u0041-\u005a), and a-z (\u0061-\u007a), and, for historical reasons, the ASCII underscore (_, or \u005f) and dollar sign ($, or \u0024). **The $ character should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems**.

(emphasis mine)

Though really, it's just a matter of you having a duplicate class name after bytecode generation. The same error would occur with two colliding class names that didn't involve `$` in the source.

**Edit to add:** The binary format is specified in [13.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1)

Comment: I think 13.1 is the part I'm after - it accurately describes what the binary name of the class will be. I would have expected there to be a caveat that binary names can't clash, but perhaps it's too obvious to bother wasting time spelling this out in the spec.