# What are the decimal delimited letters in namespaces in stacktrace on Android involving threads

Tags: java, android, stack-trace

I'm looking at deobfuscated stacktraces on firebase, and I'm wondering what these weird namespaces involving decimal delimited letters are:

**.c.c**

and

**.a.d.u$1.a**

in the below image.

The dollars signs denote anonymous inner classes (kudos to GhostCat), but what's the lettering?

E.g.for the `surface.view.c.c(boolean)` method; I have no classes named **c** in my surface.view namespace. Is **c** then a renaming of one of my own classes due to duplicates arising due to multithreading, or is it something out of the android framework (i.e. not my code)

[image: stacktrace]

Answer (score 1):

Probably these are not "anonymous" methods but simple anonymous inner classes. Those get mangled this way, and as you sometimes have to *count* anonymous things in order to come to unique names, that is where dollar and digits are coming from.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667890/mangled-nested-class-namein-the-java-language-specification) for further details.

Comment: Thanks :)...Got ya on the anonymous inner classes... but for the `surface.view.c.c(boolean)` method; I have no classes named **c** in my `surface.view` namespace.  Do you know if  **c** is then a renaming of one of my own classes due to duplicates arising due to multithreading, or is it something out of the android framework (i.e. not my code)

Comment: You are very welcome. Hope somebody else comes by who has more to say. For the record: I dont think that this should have to do anything with multi-threading. I would expect a single thread id somewhere in a stack trace.